# How to set entry point/start page for electron app on win10 correctly in production build

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have created a react app and want to wrap it in electron to run it on win10, since the App needs node-seriaport. 
Everything works fine in development mode, but I don´t get the app running properly in production mode, i.e. when packed.
The App starts on the wrong page and images and files in extra resources are not loaded properly since the routing/pathes are not correct.

The packing itself works fine, but when i run the .exe file the app starts on the 404-Route, which I have implemented as a catch all in react-router. When loggin in the chrome console, where the app actually wanted to go i see the following route: 
`pathname: "/C:/UserData/somefolder/otherfolder/dist/win-unpacked/resources/app.asar/build/index.html"`
- which would be correct if there wasn´t that `/` at the start.
I have some files in the extraResource folder, but i am not able to access this folder in production/packed mode, in the sources tab in Chrome the extraResources Folder is not part of the main app directory but is shown seperatly, meaning it is expected to be under `C:\`, how can I configure this correctly?
[image: Chrome Sources Tab]

As said in dev mode everthing works fine.
I think it all starts with the right route for the entry point, can´t someone provide me a hint what I need to do to get that working?

Here is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./public/electron.js",
  "author": "CG",
  "description": "description",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron": "set ELECTRON_START_URL=http://localhost:3000 && electron .",
    "rebuild": "./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -f -w serialport",
    "electron-pack": "build --win --x64 --dir"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^4.0.4",
    "electron-packager": "^13.1.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.4"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.wmt.wmt-1",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "directories":{
      "buildResources": "public"
    },
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "./public/extraResources/",
        "to": "extraResources",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "win": {
    "icon": "/public/img/icon.png"
  },
  "homepage": "./"
}
```

Here is the `electron.js`file:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow, protocol} = require('electron')
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

let mainWindow

const startUrl = process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL || url.format({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../build/index.html'),
  protocol: 'file:',
  slashes: true,
});

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      webSecurity: false
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', () => {
  createWindow()
});
```

Comment: have you found a solution? i am having similar issues with accessing extraResources in the builds

Comment: Unfortunately not, next thing I wanted to try is to use the windows installer, maybe this will help to set the routing properly, but didn’t have the time yet to check this out